# Video file To frame folder in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import argparse
import os

#import skvideo.io
import cv2

def main(video_path, nth_sample, output_path):   
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_num = 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    while ret:
        frame_num += 1
        if frame_num % nth_sample == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_path, 'frame_' + str(frame_num).zfill(5) + '.png'), frame)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        print (frame_num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extrace frames from a video file')

    parser.add_argument('C:/Users/Pratik/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/WhatsApp Video 2017-11-21 at 18.59.55.mp4',help='path to video file')

    parser.add_argument('-n','--5',help='Sample rate to extract every nth frame',type = int,default=1)
    parser.add_argument('-o','--C:/Users/Pratik/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/frame',help='path to output test images, defaults to out',default='out')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

I am getting the below error, I am new to python so I think I am doing some mistake in passing the variables , but I am not sure where.

```
usage: Frme.py [-h] [-n 5]
               [-o C:/USERS/PRATIK/APPDATA/LOCAL/PROGRAMS/PYTHON/PYTHON36_32/FRAME]
               C:/Users/Pratik/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/WhatsApp
               Video 2017-11-21 at 18.59.55.mp4
Frme.py: error: the following arguments are required: C:/Users/Pratik/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/WhatsApp Video 2017-11-21 at 18.59.55.mp4
```

Comment: If `argparse` is not a must, just use `sys.argv` for your parameter. By the way, your `main()` function is ok.

Comment: it seems argparse is a must , I am not able to detect what is the error in this case

Comment: The problem is solely in your usage of `argparse` -- please, provide a [mcve] and don't mix unrelated things like opencv in. | What is the intent of the first call to `parser.add_argument`?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue with little tweaking in the program, this resolves the inputted video file into the frames according to the frame numbers you have mentioned.

import argparse

import os

import sys

## import skvideo.io

import cv2

def x(video_path, nth_sample,output_path):

if not os.path.exists(output_path): os.makedirs(output_path)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

frame_num = 1

ret, frame = cap.read()

while ret:
        frame_num += 1
        if frame_num % nth_sample == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_path, 'frame_' + str(frame_num).zfill(5) + '.png'), frame)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        print (frame_num)

def main():

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extrace frames from a video file')

parser.add_argument('-v','--video_path',help='path to video file')

parser.add_argument('-l','--nth_sample',help='Sample rate to extract every nth frame',type = int)

parser.add_argument('-o','--output_path',help='path to output test images, defaults to out')

args = parser.parse_args()

x(**vars(args))

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()